# mprotect() Invalid argument in C

Tags: c, arguments, mprotect

I want to allocate 4096 Bytes with posix_memalign in the array "page", and then protect it with PROT_NONE via mprotect().
The allocation seems to work, but protect() returns 1 instead of 0. The given error code is "Invalid argument".

I think it's only a small mistake, I am not able to detect. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

```
uint8_t *page;
size_t page_size = 4096;
size_t alignment = 8;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (posix_memalign((void **) &page, alignment, page_size) != 0) perror("Allocation failed!");
    if (mprotect(page, page_size, PROT_NONE) != 0) perror("mprotect() failed!");
}
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, but I think that [`mprotect`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mprotect.html) returns *`-1`*, not `1`.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't affirm that... Test it for yourself, if you don't believe ;-)

    int main() {
        if (posix_memalign((void **) &page, alignment, page_size) != 0) perror("Allocation failed!");
        int n;
        if (n = mprotect(page, page_size, PROT_NONE) != 0) perror("mprotect() failed!");
        printf("n: %d\n",n);
    }

Comment: As for your problem, [the `mprotect` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mprotect.html) says that "The implementation may require that addr be a multiple of the page size as returned by [`sysconf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sysconf.html)". And that `EINVAL` (the error you get) is for "The *`addr`* argument is not a multiple of the page size as returned by `sysconf()`" On your system, are you *sure* the page-size is 4k?

Comment: By the way `n = mprotect(page, page_size, PROT_NONE) != 0` does *not* do what you think it does. It first evaluates `mprotect(page, page_size, PROT_NONE) != 0` and then assign the boolean `1` or `0` result to `n`. Try instead `(n = mprotect(page, page_size, PROT_NONE)) != 0`.

Comment: Very good comment! I changed it like you said, and now it shows me correctly the -1 instead of 1.
My pagesize is indeed 4096, I retrieved it with both possibilities:
    long t1 = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    long t2 = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the way in the code below ... and read better the man-pages:

> man -S3 posix_memalign
>
> man -S2 mprotect

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <unistd.h>

uint8_t *page=NULL;
size_t page_size;
size_t alignment = 8;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int blen;

    // page_size=getpagesize();
    page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);

    blen=page_size * 2;

    if (posix_memalign((void **) &page, page_size, blen) != 0)
        perror("Allocation failed!");

    if (mprotect(page, page_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE) != 0)
        perror("mprotect() failed!");
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo! It works fine for me.
I read the manpages several times before asking, but it seems that I am too stupid for it.

Comment: `int blen=page_size * 2;` sets `blen` to zero because when it's executed, `page_size` is zero.

Comment: J.Doe, as @AndrewHenle signals, my code had a bug. I edited it to solve the issue!

Comment: @J.Doe ... I've added some other edits to align the code with posix compliance and to obtain the buffer is read/write and not read/exec!

Comment: Thank you very much for your repeated effort. I noticed that alignment = 8; is never used. I am going to read the manpages now, to see the purpose for that. Have a nice day!

Comment: The problem is that alignment (the second parm of posix_memalign) shall be a multiple of the page size otherwise the posix_memalign fails. The third parameter is the amount of memory we need to use!